How to update member status after successful payment
I have a contribution form that when a member fills out the form they get re directed to Stripe checkout where they will pay the fees. Using a dummy card and test member to test this function I am able to get the dummy card to work and the payment to succeed. However I am having trouble to get my members status updated from pending status due to incomplete transaction. I've made webhooksthat use event listeners to show when the payment is successful but the membership status is still pending. I'm not sure how to fix this or if I have to make a php file that uses a post request.

If you are using the Stripe extension then i would not expect you to be being 'redirected' (ie stripe fields would show 'in' the form)) so perhaps add more details of your Stripe set up. Also there is a Sch Job for membership status so check that is enabled.

If the scheduled jobs to process webhooks and membership statuses are running it should update - we also offer the Stripe Checkout options and they show briefly as a 'Pending (Incomplete Transaction)' for the contribution and 'Pending' for the membership but update as expected when the cron jobs run.

I ran the job.process_membership cron and it still didn't update the members status. I an also getting no errors within my system status
